# Difference in string length (database - .txt file)

Tags: java, mysql, database, text-files

I'm working on a project where I load records from a database and run some validation checks on them such as pattern searching which returns me the index of a certain pattern. The records themselves can be very big, with one field up to 2 million characters. For this reason I have copied some test data into plain text files and saved them locally.

The problem I have is that when I run the tests, the strings I read from the local text file differ in length from the string inside the MySQL database. Indexes returned from the SQL database are lower (the complete string is shorter) than the indexes returned from the plain text file I stored locally.

example of database field (type = mediumtext)

```
11:00 i have started entering into this database field
12:00 continueing
13:00 some more
14:00 end of database work
```

When I check the database field for its length (using `select length(field)`) it tells me its length is 115

When i paste the exact contents of the database field into Notepad++, it tells me there are 118 characters.

I know for a fact that its not a set difference because the difference in indexes returned by my code is increasing as i go further into long strings.

My guess is that MySQL stores linebreaks/spaces/tabs differently than a .txt file.

But this is just a wild guess.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me guess: Database uses `\n` and file uses `\r\n`, so you have three aditional `\r` for the first three lines ...

Comment: *"My guess is that MySQL stores linebreaks/spaces/tabs differently than a .txt file. But this is just a wild guess."* And why do you only guess? Why don't you debug your code?

Comment: Because I dont know what the correct procedure would be to debug such an issue i will read up about the`\n` vs `\r\n`

Comment: Well, there is no big difference in debugging this and other cases. Just set a breakpoint and look into the char array of your String from the DB and the String from the file. You'll see the differences there.

Comment: but the strings look exactly the same when i debug them, if i read the database field and copy the string while debugging into a .txt, it has the same length as the .txt stored previously

Comment: No, don't do that. Copying that into the text file won't protect you from manipulations from your text editor. It still can overwrite the line endings or add other stuff like a BOM. You need to look in your IDE and the String content what Java really uses.

Comment: i found an example where the string differs 1 char in length when i read from .txt vs when i read from database, but upon inspecting the string itself, it looks identical

Comment: Do they just look identical or are they indentical? Do they have the same length in Java? If yes, then you can't rely on the length information from Notepad++ for your program.

Comment: no they differ in string.length() in java. But i want to know why they differ so I can account for it in the future. is there a way to find out?

Comment: Either check the char array of both Strings or check the byte array of both. They tell you each char/byte they contain and on of them has one additional entry there. Like "[97, 98, 99, 10]" ("abc\n") versus "[97, 98, 99, 13, 10]" ("abc\r\n").

Comment: @Tom converting the string to a char array revealed your initial suggestion was correct, the plain text file uses `\r\n` and my database uses `\n` in these positions. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: That's good to here. Now the next step is up to you: either write an answer and explain how you found the difference and how you think about fixing the issue, so a future reader can profit from this question and the answer, or delete the question if you don't think that it has any value for another person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already found out that the database is using `\n` as newline and the textfile is using `\r\n` as newline (Thanks to Tom). I found a solution for you which you maybe can use.

You could replace the \n with \r\n so it matches your text file.
You can use this: 
`REPLACE(column, '\n', '\r\n')` in your select query.